# Entity framework 6 with MVC 5 IdentityUser one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Mission: Create a list of events, each event has a list of users.
Problem: When the list of users is a class of my own i get it to work, but now i want the list of users to be the ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, and i just cant seem to get it to work.

This is my Event class and the Fighter class:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fighter> Fighters { get; set; } 
}

public class Fighter
{
    public int FighterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my context setup:

```
namespace WebApplication6.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string ExtraSetting1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>,IEventDataSource
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fighter> Fighters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasMany(x => x.Fighters).WithMany();
        }

        IQueryable<Event> IEventDataSource.Events
        {
            get { return Events; }
        } 
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, the tables are created as i want them to:

[image: Event > Fighters]

Now when i want to completly remove the Fighter class and replace it with the ApplicationUser class, i just cant find out how to get it to work. This is my attempt:

1. Replace ICollection(Fighter) in the Event class, with ICollection(IUser)
2. comment out all Fighter class related (dbset)

The error i get when i delete the database and try to do a "update-database" is:
**The navigation property 'Fighters' is not a declared property on type 'Event'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.**

I understand that this is a configuration issue and i need to explain to EF how i want it to be related, but after hours of trying different stuff i was hoping a kind soul would just tell me what im doing wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are obviously not removing all references to Fighter.  For example, are you changing the OnModelCreating method to map event to IUser instead of Fighter?

Comment: I have double checked and there is no "Fighters" code left, however I have not changed the name of the property on the Event class, it´s still called "Fighters". In the OnModelCreating method i never specify a Type, its derived from the Event class in : modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasMany(x => x.Fighters).WithMany();
And the Event class has IUser in it.

Comment: Well, that's what's causing the confusion... It has nothing to do with Fighter then, and if you'd changed it to Users, you'd see an error for Users then.